# $P \in \text {SO}_{n} (\Bbb R)$ if $P$ is orthogonal and $P^{-1} A P$ is diagonal with $A$ symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix. Then what I know is that there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P$ is a diagonal matrix or in other words $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable. Can we say that $P \in \text {SO}_{n} (\Bbb R)\ $ i.e. $\ P \in \text {O}_{n} (\Bbb R)$ with $\det (P) = 1\ $?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\det(P) = -1$, let $p_1$ be the first column of $P$, and replace $p_1$ by $-p_1$.

Comment: Let the resultant matrix be $Q.$ Then how do I ensure that $Q^{-1} A Q = P^{-1} A P\ $?

Comment: Oh! I see. That's because if $p_1$ is an eigenvector corresponding to some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ so is $-p_1.$

Comment: $AQ = [A(-p_1) \cdots Ap_n] = [\lambda_1(-p_1) \cdots \lambda_n p_n] = QD$. It's also easy to verify that $Q$ remains orthogonal.